# loop through ActiveX Checkboxes, rename and change linked cell then copy and repeat

Tags: excel, vba, loops, checkbox, activex

I'm Trying to create a macro which will rename and then change the linked cell of a number of active x check boxes then copy down a new set and repeat the process.  it would need to be looped about 200 times. basically i need 200 sets of checkboxes with the properties (name) as follows:

SET 1 (of active x check-boxes)

- FL1MON (Link Cell: C5)
- FL1TUE (Link Cell: D5)
- FL1WED (Link Cell: E5)
- FL1THU (Link Cell: F5)
- FL1FRI (Link Cell: G5)
- FL1SAT (Link Cell: H5)
- FL1SUN (Link Cell: I5)

SET 2 (of active x check-boxes)

- FL2MON (Link Cell: C25)
- FL2TUE (Link Cell: D25)
- FL2WED (Link Cell: E25)
- FL2THU (Link Cell: F25)
- FL2FRI (Link Cell: G25)
- FL2SAT (Link Cell: H25)
- FL2SUN (Link Cell: I25)

(and repeated)...

I have some code attached below; however, I believe I'm most likely going in the wrong direction with it. Also , I have yet to figure out how I will be changing the linked cell in the loop.

```
Sub CopyDown_Boxes()

Dim oles1 As OLEObject
 Dim oles2 As OLEObject
  Dim oles3 As OLEObject
   Dim oles4 As OLEObject
    Dim oles5 As OLEObject
     Dim oles6 As OLEObject
      Dim oles7 As OLEObject

i = (x * 15) + 5

For x = 1 To 7


Set oles1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Flight Schedule").OLEObjects("CheckBox1")
Set oles2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Flight Schedule").OLEObjects("CheckBox2")
Set oles3 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Flight Schedule").OLEObjects("CheckBox3")
Set oles4 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Flight Schedule").OLEObjects("CheckBox4")
Set oles5 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Flight Schedule").OLEObjects("CheckBox5")
Set oles6 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Flight Schedule").OLEObjects("CheckBox6")
Set oles7 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Flight Schedule").OLEObjects("CheckBox7")

    oles1.Name = "FL" & x & "MON"
    oles2.Name = "FL" & x & "TUE"
    oles3.Name = "FL" & x & "WED"
    oles4.Name = "FL" & x & "THU"
    oles5.Name = "FL" & x & "FRI"
    oles6.Name = "FL" & x & "SAT"
    oles7.Name = "FL" & x & "SUN"

Worksheets("Flight Schedule").Shapes.Range(Array("FL" & x & "MON", "FL" & x & "MON", "FL" & x & "MON", _
    "FL" & x & "MON", "FL" & x & "MON", "FL" & x & "MON", "FL" & x & "MON")).Select
Selection.Copy
Range("B" & i).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Next x

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slightly different approach perhaps to give you an option.  I have used alignment with cells as the basis of positioning the checkboxes and positioned the sets vertically to align with the 'linked cell' rows.  This example just generates them to the active worksheet.

[image: checkbox sets]

```
Sub multiCheck()
Dim chkRow As Long, chkCol As Long, LastRow As Long, x As Long
Dim chkLeft As Double, chkTop As Double, chkHeight As Double
Dim chkWidth As Double, numOfSets As Double, linkCellSpace As Double
Dim linkCellRow As Double, linkCellColStart As Double, setSpacing As Integer
Dim chkSet As Integer, chkSpace As Integer
Dim wkArr() As Variant

'initial values
chkRow = 3
chkCol = 2
chkSpace = 2
setSpacing = 6
LastRow = 20
linkCellRow = 5
linkCellSpace = 20
linkCellColStart = 2
'no of week sets
numOfSets = 3

wkArr() = Array("MON", "TUE", "WED", "THU", "FRI", "SAT", "SUN")

    'for each week set
    For chkSet = 0 To numOfSets - 1
            'for each day of week
            For x = 1 To 7
                chkRow = chkRow + chkSpace
                chkLeft = Cells(chkRow, chkCol).Left
                chkTop = Cells(chkRow, chkCol).Top
                chkHeight = Cells(chkRow, chkCol).Height
                chkWidth = Cells(chkRow, chkCol).Width

                ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Add(chkLeft, chkTop, chkWidth, chkHeight).Select
                    With Selection
                        .Name = "FL" & chkSet + 1 & wkArr(x - 1)
                        .Caption = .Name
                        .Display3DShading = True
                        .LinkedCell = Cells(linkCellRow + (linkCellSpace * chkSet), linkCellColStart + x).Address
                    End With
            Next x
        chkRow = chkRow + setSpacing
    Next chkSet
End Sub
```

**EDIT FOR ACTIVE-X CHECKBOXES THAT SIZE/MOVE WITH CELLS**

Amendments as requested.  Set `flightSheet` to your appropriate worksheet. The code sets the checkboxes to `FALSE` by default.

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Sub multiCheckActiveX()
Dim chkBox As New OLEObject
Dim flightSheet As Worksheet
Dim chkRow As Long, chkCol As Long, LastRow As Long, x As Long
Dim chkLeft As Double, chkTop As Double, chkHeight As Double
Dim chkWidth As Double, numOfSets As Double, linkCellSpace As Double
Dim linkCellRow As Double, linkCellColStart As Double, setSpacing As Integer
Dim chkSet As Integer, chkSpace As Integer
Dim wkArr() As Variant

'initial values
chkRow = 3
chkCol = 2
chkSpace = 2
setSpacing = 6
LastRow = 20
linkCellRow = 5
linkCellSpace = 20
linkCellColStart = 2
'no of week sets
numOfSets = 3

Set flightSheet = Sheets("Sheet2")

wkArr() = Array("MON", "TUE", "WED", "THU", "FRI", "SAT", "SUN")

With flightSheet
    'for each week set
    For chkSet = 0 To numOfSets - 1
            'for each day of week
            For x = 1 To 7
                chkRow = chkRow + chkSpace
                chkLeft = .Cells(chkRow, chkCol).Left
                chkTop = .Cells(chkRow, chkCol).Top
                chkHeight = .Cells(chkRow, chkCol).Height
                chkWidth = .Cells(chkRow, chkCol).Width

                Set chkBox = .OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.CheckBox.1")
                    With chkBox
                        .Left = chkLeft
                        .Top = chkTop
                        .Width = chkWidth
                        .Height = chkHeight
                        .Name = "FL" & chkSet + 1 & wkArr(x - 1)
                        .Object.Caption = .Name
                        .Object.SpecialEffect = 2
                        .LinkedCell = flightSheet.Cells(linkCellRow + (linkCellSpace * chkSet), linkCellColStart + x).Address
                        .Object.Value = False
                        .Placement = xlMoveAndSize
                    End With
            Next x
        chkRow = chkRow + setSpacing
    Next chkSet
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This approach is getting much closer to what I need; however, the checkboxes need to by activex since they will need to size and moved with cells (There are filters present on the sheet and form controls are not completely filterable since they cannot size with cells) is there a way this can be modified for activex ?

Comment: @Moehling - see Edit to my answer.